# Internet sharing disabling Macbook Wifi

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing, ethernet, tethering

So I wanted to share the Ethernet connection through my Wifi to my phone, since it is having problems connecting to my router at home.

My Wifi works fine on it's own. My ethernet connection works fine on it's own.

But when I plug in my Ethernet connection and turn internet sharing on it disables my wifi. When I try to click "Turn on WIFI" nothing happens.

As you can see in the top right corner the Wifi is disabled and I can't enable it.

[image]

After the Internet sharing disables my Wifi I need to turn off internet sharing and restart my macbook for the Wifi to switch back on again.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

I have tried looking for alternative hotspot software for mac, maybe this will solve my problems but couldn't find any of those either.

Comment: I am missing a 'padlock' in the lower left corner. Do you have admin rights? For others, does he needs admin rights?

Comment: No, it ('padlock') is absent on this pane.

Comment: End of last year, many Yosemite users experienced lots of problems with Wi-Fi. It was turning off very often by itself. May be this guide will be of any help: http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/

Comment: @ranklord the OS is Yosemite, the padlock shows in other settings, just not sharing. I will try this guide. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GregoryPeck, well, I hope it is Yosemite 10.10.3 ;) Yes, I know about padlock. I just replied to CousinCocaine that on this particular pane (Sharing) it is absent. If this guide won’t help, let's search further.

Comment: @ranklord it is actually 10.10.2. Might this be the problem ?

Comment: @ranklord updating fixed the wifi issue !! Thanks a mill. Hopefully it solves all wifi issues because other than this Yosemite has been magnificent

Comment: @GregoryPeck Good. That's what I thought since they fixed wi-fi issue in the update. Happy was able to help :) Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1):

I was also scratching my head just to share my one iPhone internet to tether via my iMac. It was so silly what solved the problem.

Uncheck the internet sharing checkbox in sharing system preferences.
[image: Uncheck the internet sharing checkbox in sharing system preferences.]
After unchecking the internet fields were enabled.
[image: After unchecking the internet fields were enabled.]